# How to make batch queue with arrayList when loop?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

let's say I have this array:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Then I want to divide this array for each 2 batch with 5 array value:

```
a[0] = [1,2,3,4,5];
a[1] = [6,7,8,9,10];
```

This is my code until now keep trying.It should insert to db when batch has been slice for each job for 100 array value.

```js
BatchList = new Meteor.Collection('batch_list');

var arrayAssetList = Asset.find({}, { _id: 1});

var data = [];

arrayAssetList.forEach(function(key){

  data.push(key._id)

});

var arraySize = arrayAssetList.count() / 100;
var slice, sliceTo;

for(var i=0; i<arraySize; i++){

  if(i == 0){
    slice = 0
  } {
    slice = 100*i
  }

  if(i>1){

    sliceTo = 100*i;

  }

  BatchList.insert({ data: data.slice(slice,sliceTo)});

}
```

it should be like this:

```js
[{

  _id: '()@()#@)#*()@*#',
  size: 100,
  data: [1,2,3,4,100]

},{

  _id: 'sdfsdfnnn3',
  size: 100,
  data: [100,101,102,103,200]

}]
```

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: I'm trying on queue the job for each batch have 100 array value.

so, it should be the query will be not slow to execute.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some code sample where you want to manipulate the data, is it on client or server side?

Comment: kind check my code, i have put my code above

Comment: add some `console.log()`'s and check that each stage is as you expect